# iam trying to authenticate another salesforce org(server org) using username,password and security token of server org from client salesforce org

Tags: integration

when iam trying to get access token by using call out program provided below iam getting this error:

> response::System.HttpResponse[Status=Unauthorized, StatusCode=401]

Code:

```
public class DataRetrievalCallout {
    public static HttpResponse getData(String query) {
        // Build the endpoint URL using the query passed in
        String endpoint = 'https://ksheerabdhi-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v49.0/query?q=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(query, 'UTF-8');
        // Create the HTTP request
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + getAccessToken());
        // Send the HTTP request
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        system.debug('response::'+res);
        return res;
    }
    
    private static String getAccessToken() {
        // Build the login endpoint URL
        String endpoint = 'https://ksheerabdhi-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token';
        // Create the HTTP request
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        req.setBody('grant_type=password&username=k*********m8@gmail.com&password=********+q4TapVAPDptSpauZSzNetPlW');
        // Send the HTTP request
        Http h = new Http();
        HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
        // Extract the access token from the response
        Map<String, Object> responseJson = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
        String accessToken = (String) responseJson.get('access_token');
        system.debug('accessToken::'+accessToken);
        return accessToken;
    }
}
```

I also added this url https://ksheerabdhi-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com in remote site settings client side.
Note: Here just iam trying to authenticate another salesforce org(server org) using username,password and security token of server org.
Any suggestions or help?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to use [named credentials](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.named_credentials_about.htm&type=5)(external credentials) so you don't need to keep sensitive information like credentials in apex or custom metadata.

for salesforce you can look into connecting over [oauth using connected apps](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_oauth_and_connected_apps.htm)(in your target org)
working this way allows you to delegate the authentication and access tokens to salesforce itself so you can focus on making your api calls

your code will then look similar to this

```
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint('callout:My_Named_Credential/some_path');
req.setMethod('GET');
Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
System.debug(res.getBody());
```

where My_Named_Credential is the name of your named credential and some_path will be /data/v49.0/query?q= + your query